# Is there a better way to write my python code

Tags: python

I am getting used to coding in python by now and am trying to create a code that repeats any input backwards, I don't know how to condense the code or make it so that I don't have to press enter after every word or phrase. Here is my code so far...

```
a=input()
b=input()
if(b==""):
    print(a)
c=input()
if(c==""):
    print(b,a)
d=input()
if(d==""):
    print(c,b,a)
e=input()
if(e==""):
    print(d,c,b,a)
f=input()
if(f==""):
    print(e,d,c,b,a)
g=input()
if(g==""):
    print(f,e,d,c,b,a)
h=input()
if(h==""):
    print(g,f,e,d,c,b,a)
```

Comment: Use a string or list rather than many variables.

Comment: As a side note, read [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008). Even if this structure were the best one, `if not b:` is clearer than `if (b==""):`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) to reverse a list. This applies to strings too, since they are essentially a list of characters.

```
>>> a = raw_input('type a word')
type a word
hello

>>> a[::-1]
'olleh'
```

Comment: I think he's trying to reverse the order of words, not reverse each word. Although I'm not sure…

Comment: Also, don't give a 2.x-only answer to someone using 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know how to … make it so that I don't have to press enter after every word or phrase.

So you want to input a bunch of words on a single line, and then print those words in reverse order?

Well, `input` always reads a whole line. If you want to split that line into separate words, you call the `split` method. So:

```
>>> a = input()
Here are some words
>>> words = a.split()
>>> print(words)
['Here', 'are', 'some', 'words']
```

---

Now, if you want to print them in reverse order, you can use `reversed`, or slice notation:

```
>>> for word in reversed(words):
...     print(word)
words
some
are
Here
```

If you wanted to reverse each word, you can use `reversed` again, together with `join`, or you could use slice notation:

```
>>> for word in reversed(words):
...     print(''.join(reversed(word)))
sdrow
emos
era
ereH
```

---

What if you really *did* want to read a bunch of lines in, until you got an empty one?

For that, put them in a list, not a bunch of separate variables:

```
>>> lines = []
>>> while True:
...     line = input()
...     if not line:
...         break
...     lines.append(line)
Here are some words
And some more

>>> lines
['Here are some words', 'And some more']
```

You can actually simplify that loop, but it might be a little advanced to understand at this point:

```
>>> lines = iter(input, '')
```